# Storing changes original?

Tags: python, string, list, types

bactuals is a list of strings. So is bpeaks.

```
actuals=bactuals[1:]
peaks=bpeaks[1:]
```

If I look at bactuals now, I see that it is still a list of strings. If I do the following, though:

```
actuals=bactuals[1:]
peaks=bpeaks[1:]
actuals=bactuals
peaks=bpeaks
```

(I realize that the above is an absurd piece of code to have, but I was testing to find the root of another issue.)

bactuals is suddenly now a list of types. How? How could the mere act or storing one thing into another thing change the type of the original?

Comment: Show us what it does.

Comment: It won't let me paste the entirety (or even a small snippet) of bactuals in because it's too large. As I said, it's a list of strings. If I run the code containing the first, what I expect comes out. If the only thing I change is add in those two extra lines, bactuals suddenly becomes a list where all the elements are type<list>.

Comment: You're going to need to provide some more context though.  If I run this code, I don't see the result you're getting.  Can you create a Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (http://sscce.org/)?  This will also probably have the side effect of helping you figure your problem out.

Comment: How and where are you generating the output? If you put `print(bactuals)` between the lines, do the results differ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How could the mere act or storing one thing into another thing change
>   the type of the original?

By having a setter that modifies the object passed in:

```
class C(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._actuals = []

    @property
    def actuals(self):
        return self._actuals

    @actuals.setter
    def actuals(self, value):
        self._actuals = value
        self._actuals[:] = [int(s) for s in self._actuals]


bactuals = ["1", "2", "3"]
c = C()
c.actuals = bactuals
```

The setter stores each item in the list as a different type (int), and since this was done by accessing the indices instead of creating a new list, this modifies the original.

If this is what's happening, you wouldn't see it in the first case because `bactuals[1:]` actually creates a new list, leaving `bactuals` unaffected. A workaround would be to pass a copy (`bactuals[:]`) to the setter, but a better option would be to fix the setter so that it creates a new list itself.

Answer (score 0):

Your example isn't repeatable.  This works as I'd expect.

```
>>> bactuals = ['a','b','c']
>>> actuals = bactuals[1:]
>>> actuals
['b','c']
>>> actuals = bactuals
>>> actuals
['a', 'b', 'c']
```